# How to make a drop down menu with half-transparent background-color on IE8?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, opacity, nav

I'm trying to make a dropdown menu which background-color is half-transparent.
It works just fine on all browsers except on IE8.

When the menu is half-transparent using the follwing Filter, it looks better but the dropdown menu does not show. I made the background-color of the menu white to solve this problem.

Is it possible to make the background half-transparent and the dropdown menu still work on IE8?

Filter

```
        filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=0,StartColorStr=#CCffffff,EndColorStr=#CCffffff);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=0,StartColorStr=#CCffffff,EndColorStr=#CCffffff)";
```

html

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<style type="text/css">
.inner { background-color: #fff !important
}
#menu li ul { background-color: #fff;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->

<header>
 <div class="inner">
  <nav>
  <ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">menu1</a></li>       
    <li><a href="#">menu2</a>
 <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li> <a href="#">submenu_1</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#">submenu_2</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#">submenu_3</a> </li>
      </ul> </li>
      <li><a href="greeting.html">menu4</a> </li>
    <li><a href="greeting.html">menu5</a>
    </li> 
  </ul>
</nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

css

```
.inner {
margin: 0 auto;
z-index: 999;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
position: fixed;
left: 1%;
width: 100%;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=0,StartColorStr=#99ffffff,EndColorStr=#99ffffff);
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=0,StartColorStr=#99ffffff,EndColorStr=#99ffffff)";
}

#menu {
margin-top: 31px;
margin-left: 15%;
float: left;
width: 70%;
}

#menu li {
text-align: center;
margin-left: 60px;
display: inline-block;
float: left;
height: 50px;
}

#menu li:hover > ul {
display: block;
}

#menu li > a {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
  height: 50px;
}

#menu li ul {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
     filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=0,StartColorStr=#99ffffff,EndColorStr=#99ffffff);
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=0,StartColorStr=#99ffffff,EndColorStr=#99ffffff)";
left: 0;
top: 100%;
width: 100%;
z-index: 2000;
}

#menu li:hover ul.sub-menu {
display: block;
}


#menu li ul.sub-menu li {
float: none;
margin-left: 0px;
width: 130px;
height: auto;
padding: 0;

}

#menu li ul.sub-menu {
display: none;
position: absolute;
width: 130px;
padding-left: 0;
   left: 430px;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: Cut a 10 * 10 `png` image and use as `background-image` with repeat.

Comment: thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your filter hex code is incorrect.

The two characters at the start of the hex code denote the opacity

`rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)` would be equivalent to `(startColorstr=#80FFFFFF,endColorstr=#80FFFFFF)`

`00` is transparent and `FF` opaque. Here's the full mapping:

```
100% — FF
95% — F2
90% — E6
85% — D9
80% — CC
75% — BF
70% — B3
65% — A6
60% — 99
55% — 8C
50% — 80
45% — 73
40% — 66
35% — 59
30% — 4D
25% — 40
20% — 33
15% — 26
10% — 1A
5% — 0D
0% — 00
```

So this: `background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);`

Equates to :
    `filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=0,StartColorStr=#E6ffffff,EndColorStr=#E6ffffff);`

This should be in your `<head>` consitional styles **not** your main CSS sheet as it also required `background:none;` to be applied.

Note I don't have IE8 so I cannot test.

Details provided by [**CSS Tricks**](https://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/)

Comment: thank you for your advice and the list. The filter hex code worked fine as it was in the main CSS on IE8, ignoring the problem with the pull down menu. but anyway, I will be careful to write the right code. Thank you!